# Problems with Bootable USB on macbook pro w/ ventura 13.2.1 (Apple M2, 2022)

Tags: boot, usb, macbook, apple

I'm a total rookie so please be patient. I'd like to try Ubuntu on my macbook pro laptop using a live version on an USB stick but there is no way it sees the USB when i restart in recovery mode

I downloaded ubuntu-22.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso and prepared the usb stick with BalenaEtcher but there's no way the computer sees the USB as bootable option.

Not sure if it can be a matter of the fact the USB is connected through an hub to the laptop (USB3.0 while the laptop port is USB-C) or some filevault/security settings issue. I browsed various times through the security options (e.g. i had do allow VeraCrypt to have it working) and forums online without finding anything helpful to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The amd64 version of Ubuntu, which you downloaded, will not work with ARM processors.

For a smooth experience, use [Asahi Linux](https://asahilinux.org/) instead. It is built specifically for ARM Macs, and is actively developed. It can be installed with a single command in the MacOS terminal, as mentioned in the main webpage.

It can also be easily uninstalled.

[Here](https://asahilinux.org/fedora/#device-support) is the device support page.

Please note that Asahi Linux is now based on Fedora, which is not a version of Ubuntu, and questions about it are not supported on this site. But you can get support at the [Asahi Fedora Project Matrix](https://matrix.to/#/#asahi:fedoraproject.org).

Comment: Thanks, i checked the Asahi Linux website but i can't find if it's possible to create an USB live version of the SO, the only command i fund for the Terminal seems the straight installer...

Comment: The point is you don't even have to create an usb installer. Run that command and it will automatically configure the dual boot